# grep for names with variable number of forward slashes

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a column with two types of names (embedded within a longer string).

names are like `A/HK/RATATA/Lol(2007)` or `A/chickapig/RATATA/Lol(2003)`.

I would like to filter using a regular expression based on the number of "/" within each name.

```
Example: 
Influenza A virus (A/chicken/Wenzhou/642/2013(H9N2))
Influenza A virus (A/chicken/Wenzhou/643/2013(H9N2))
Influenza A virus (A/chicken/Wenzhou/644/2013(H9N2))
Influenza A virus (A/Wenzhou/mamamam/2013(H9N2))
```

I would only like to filter the row containing Influenza A virus (A/Wenzhou/mamamam/2013(H9N2))

I tried using \ to scape /, not even sure if it makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is based on the count of `/`, use `str_count` to `filter` the rows

```
library(dplyr)
n <- 3
df %>%
   filter(str_count(col1, fixed("/")) ==  n)
```

-output

```
                                           col1
1 Influenza A virus (A/Wenzhou/mamamam/2013(H9N2))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c("Influenza A virus (A/chicken/Wenzhou/642/2013(H9N2))", 
"Influenza A virus (A/chicken/Wenzhou/643/2013(H9N2))", "Influenza A virus (A/chicken/Wenzhou/644/2013(H9N2))", 
"Influenza A virus (A/Wenzhou/mamamam/2013(H9N2))")),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @akrun's solution we could do it with `nchar` in combination with `gsub`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

# example tibble
df <- tibble(x = c("Influenza A virus (A/chicken/Wenzhou/642/2013(H9N2))",
             "Influenza A virus (A/chicken/Wenzhou/643/2013(H9N2))",
             "Influenza A virus (A/chicken/Wenzhou/644/2013(H9N2))",
             "Influenza A virus (A/Wenzhou/mamamam/2013(H9N2))"))

df %>% 
  filter(nchar(x) - nchar(gsub('\\/', '', x)) == 3)
```

```
  x                                               
  <chr>                                           
1 Influenza A virus (A/Wenzhou/mamamam/2013(H9N2))
```